# Specify window.location for each test file for Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am upgrading to Jest 22 and I got some problem about mocking `window.location`. In past, this method is work fine but not work after upgraded.

```
Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'href', {
    writable: true,
    value: 'https://example.com/abc',
});
```

I have read over Jest documentation, there is a way to mock `window.location` in `package.json` as a config like this.

```
"jest": {
    "testURL": "https://example.com/home"
}
```

This is work fine in case all tests use the same URL.

Is there any way I can mock `window.location.href` inside the test file.

I'm using

```
"@types/jest": "^22.2.3",
"jest": "^22.4.3",
"@types/enzyme": "^3.1.10",
"enzyme": "^3.3.0",
```

**Update**

Here is usage of `window.location` inside my components

```
const currentPage = window.location.href.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1];
```

Answer (score 13):

[Solution from jest collaborator for June 2019](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/890):

> ```
> delete global.window.location;
> global.window = Object.create(window);
> global.window.location = {
>   port: '123',
>   protocol: 'http:',
>   hostname: 'localhost',
> }
> ```

Comment: Cannot edit but don't forget after deleting the global.window.location to add it back after each test, like const { location } = window; afterEach(() => {
  window.location = location;
});

Answer (score 0):

There is no really nice way at the moment. As we use react-router I dent to use it for all url changes and mock it in the tests. If you don't use react-router just create a `location` module like this:

```
export default (location) => window.location = location
```

that can be easily mocked in the test