# Jest/Testing - Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have a simple react comp. which I want to test the onclick handler on:

### react-comp

```
const CallButton = ({ phoneLabel, phoneNumber }) => {
    function onClick(e) {
        trackNavigationClick({...});
    }

    return (
        <a href={`tel:${phoneNumber}`} className={styles.callButton} onClick={onClick}>
            <Icon name="phone" size={20} className={styles.callIcon} />
            <span>{phoneLabel}</span>
            <sup className={styles.asterisk}>*</sup>
        </a>
    );
};
```

Now when testing, the test runs through:

### jest test

```
jest.mock('../../../helper/trackNavigation', () => ({
    trackNavigationClick: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('CallButton', () => {
    it('should track on click', async () => {
        const phoneLabel = 'Hotline';
        const phoneNumber = '089/12345';
        const { queryByText } = renderWithIntl(
            <CallButton phoneLabel={phoneLabel} phoneNumber={phoneNumber} />,
        );

        fireEvent.click(queryByText(phoneLabel));
        
        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(trackNavigationClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith({...});
        });
    });
});
```

but I get an ugly error in the console:

```
  console.error
Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)
    at module.exports (/Users/lekoma/evelin/header-fragment/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:9:17)
    at navigateFetch (/Users/lekoma/evelin/header-fragment/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/navigation.js:76:3)
    at exports.navigate (/Users/lekoma/evelin/header-fragment/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/navigation.js:54:3)
    at Timeout.setTimeout (/Users/lekoma/evelin/header-fragment/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils-impl.js:81:7)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:535:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:479:7) undefined
```

Does someone of you know how this fix this error, without modifing the production code? I also saw there is alrady a stackoverflow-ref: [Specify window.location for each test file for Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49975981/specify-window-location-for-each-test-file-for-jest) but that did not help me, or at least did not know where to use the workaorund in my test.

### Edit

if necessarry I can also provide code of trackNavigationClick func:

```
export function trackNavigationClick({ e, item, navigationItems, category, action, label }) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    trackAnalyticsEvent({
        category,
        action,
        label: label || getTrackingLabel(item, navigationItems),
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you, please, specify code for `trackNavigationClick`?

Comment: @MarcoLe I think it has to do with url change. Your CallButton wrapped with an anchor element, which I think on simulate of click it changes url.
I get this error too, in one of my recent tests where I do change the url deliberately in  a login component.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this problem @MarcoLe?

Comment: No, just ignored it as it was "only" a ugly a log in the console, but test was running fine